# jinja2 unpack unknown number of values

Tags: python, flask, web, jinja2

I'm wondering how to unpack a tuple with an unknown number of variables in Jinja2. Specifically, I'm looking for an equivalent syntax or approach in Jinja2 that achieves the same effect as the following Python code:

```
a,*_ = d,f,g,e
```

In the Python code above, the *_ syntax allows me to discard the remaining variables in the tuple. Is there a similar construct or technique in Jinja2 that allows for this type of unpacking and discarding?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that's a very illustrative example. You could simplify it to `a = d` to accomplish the same thing, or `a = mytuple[0]` if you actually have a tuple variable. Both of these options would work fine in Jinja.

Comment: Inddeed I agree., but I was looking for something more general to use, like for example in for loops `{% for a,b, *_ in lst %}`, there your example won't work, and I have to specify the number of variables that there is in each element of lst.

Comment: @ItayLev I ran into the same problem with the for loop. Maybe update the question to reflect the problem more precisely?

Comment: @cstork It is a general question not just regarding a loop, but I would appericate if you can help me rephrase the quesetion to write it more precisely

Comment: Ok, sure. If you'd ask it regarding the for-loop other approaches would also be valid, like a "take filter" on the list that's being iterated over. By "take filter" I mean something like `take` in Haskell or, I think, in itertools. Sadly, no such filter exists.